RAG with Sources
So I’ve been looking at a lot of tutorials to build a basic RAG search which does the following:

Takes the user query and put it into the state “user_query”
Searches the internet for results. These results are then populated
as text in the state “internet_search_results” field with the url
and title of the text
Does the same but searches the local database and populates the
state “local_search_results” field with the post ID and title of the
search results.
Then passes the state with the information above into a summariser
function which uses GPT 3.5 to return structured output with the
following fields: (i) the text response, (ii) an array of the
sources which include the title, the type (web search or local
post), and either the url or the post ID.

I’m at a loss on this as can’t find any good tutorials for this.
